# What are the disadvantages of a Kernel SVM compared to a Linear SVM in an expanded feature space?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, pattern-recognition, kernel-density

This was a question asked in my exam.
I gave the following answer to which I was given  0 points. The Professor is not even agreeing to give any partial credit and is not telling me what is wrong with my answer. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with my answer?

This is the answer I have given in my exam.
The disadvantages are:
1) If the data is linearly separable in the expanded feature space, the linear SVM maximizes the margin better and can lead to a sparser solution.
2) When there is a large dataset linear SVM takes lesser time to train and predict compared to a Kernelized SVM in the expanded feature space.
3) Kernelized SVM could overfit generating more complex trained SVM models when compared to a linear SVM.

Comment: Looks enough, maybe The Professor wanted to more detailed mathematical description.

Comment: No, I don't think so. She could have given partial credit if I was missing some Mathematical description.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's alright in my opinion. I'd definitely agree with your second answer. One important thing to mention here is, the Kernel SVM needs more parameters and hence, it's harder to train and to choose a sufficient set of those parameters.

[image: RBF Kernel]

Think of the RBF Kernel for example, it needs a the typical *C* parameter as the linear SVM does, but in addition to this, it needs the *Sigma* (often called *Gamma*) parameter which is the standard deviation of the normal distribution. So, to determine a good setting for both parameters, one has to use methods like *Grid-Search*.